# No my app name shown in "Open in" menu for new registered file type on ios

Tags: ios, file-type

I've added custom file type ".hex" for my app and associated it with my app (followed [this tutorial](https://stevenpsmith.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/using-custom-file-types-to-import-data-into-your-ios-apps/)).
Anyway when testing in email app (long tap on attached file) "open in" menu is shown and my app icon is shown but no my app name appended:

[image]

If tap "Quick Look" i can see provided by me file type description, so i'm sure file type icon and description is used as expected. Also i can tap my app icon and `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` will be invoked as expected.

My app icon and name is shown in apps list as usual. Testing on iPad 2 on iOS 7.1.

Comment: The fact that your app icon is shown and working correctly for this file type is a very good sign! So this must be something about how your app name is specified. Do you have a CFBundleDisplayName? Is it localized?

Comment: Well, it's actually working as i can get `openURL` event fired. But app name is now shown. The app is not localized. I've just typed target type and it's shown in apps list. I've also tried to rename target and reinstall the app and it's displayed with renamed name. But still no app name in "open in" menu.

Comment: But you didn't answer my question about the CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: I'm not sure where is it. I can see `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` in "Bundle name" in Info.plist.

Comment: No `CFBundleDisplayName` found in Info.plist if open as text file

Comment: Thanks, matt. You were right. I've added "Bundle display name" property with `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` value in Info.plist editor which actually added `CFBundleDisplayName ` in Info.plist. And the problem is solved. Please edit your comment as answer and i will take it

Comment: That's great because I was just guessing! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to add a "Bundle Display Name" (`CFBundleDisplayName`) key to your *Info.plist* file.